redis returned some data twice
I have 2 redis data (set using hset). The data is displayed in the screenshot below

As you can see under product, there's only 2 data there. On the right is the contents of one of the data.
I then run this command FT.SEARCH idx:product * SORTBY rating DESC
Somehow the command returns 3 data (I've manually added newline under each data):
> FT.SEARCH idx:product * SORTBY rating DESC
3
product:BUSINESS#imintest1@gmail.com##product#bolayam11
rating
3.33333333333
location
101.77498841004687,2.8133696789220335
image
https://static4.buysellads.net/uu/5/151247/1716733956-ServerAstra_Ad_300x250_2.png
description
serverrrry
price
3.4

product:BUSINESS#imintest1@gmail.com##product#kepakayam1
rating
3.2
location
101.77498841004687,2.8133696789220335
image
https://lowendbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/supermicro-logo-1024x1024.png
description
kepak ayam
price
3.4

product:BUSINESS#imintest1@gmail.com##product#bolayam11
location
101.77498841004687,2.8133696789220335
image
https://static4.buysellads.net/uu/5/151247/1716733956-ServerAstra_Ad_300x250_2.png
description
serverrrry
price
3.4

Why do this happen? I'm expecting only 2 data.
Update:
Here's the FT.INFO idx:product
> FT.INFO idx:product
index_name
idx:product
index_options
index_definition
key_type
HASH
prefixes
product:
default_score
1
attributes
identifier
description
attribute
description
type
TEXT
WEIGHT
1
identifier
location
attribute
location
type
GEO
SORTABLE
identifier
rating
attribute
rating
type
NUMERIC
SORTABLE
UNF
identifier
sold
attribute
sold
type
NUMERIC
SORTABLE
UNF
identifier
price
attribute
price
type
NUMERIC
SORTABLE
UNF
identifier
additionalInfo
attribute
additionalInfo
type
TEXT
WEIGHT
1
NOINDEX
num_docs
3
max_doc_id
7
num_terms
6
num_records
33
inverted_sz_mb
0.001186370849609375
vector_index_sz_mb
0
total_inverted_index_blocks
27
offset_vectors_sz_mb
1.239776611328125e-5
doc_table_size_mb
3.337860107421875e-4
sortable_values_size_mb
3.8051605224609375e-4
key_table_size_mb
8.296966552734375e-5
tag_overhead_sz_mb
0
text_overhead_sz_mb
2.002716064453125e-4
total_index_memory_sz_mb
0.0022373199462890625
geoshapes_sz_mb
0
records_per_doc_avg
11
bytes_per_record_avg
37.69696807861328
offsets_per_term_avg
0.39393940567970276
offset_bits_per_record_avg
8
hash_indexing_failures
8
total_indexing_time
2.7839999198913574
indexing
0
percent_indexed
1
number_of_uses
447
cleaning
0
gc_stats
bytes_collected
0
total_ms_run
0
total_cycles
0
average_cycle_time_ms
nan
last_run_time_ms
0
gc_numeric_trees_missed
0
gc_blocks_denied
0
cursor_stats
global_idle
0
global_total
0
index_capacity
128
index_total
0
dialect_stats
dialect_1
1
dialect_2
0
dialect_3
0
dialect_4
0
Index Errors
indexing failures
8
last indexing error
Invalid geo string
last indexing error key
product:USER#test2@email.com##product#bolayam11
field statistics
identifier
description
attribute
description
Index Errors
indexing failures
0
last indexing error
N/A
last indexing error key
N/A
identifier
location
attribute
location
Index Errors
indexing failures
8
last indexing error
Invalid geo string
last indexing error key
product:USER#test2@email.com##product#bolayam11
identifier
rating
attribute
rating
Index Errors
indexing failures
0
last indexing error
N/A
last indexing error key
N/A
identifier
sold
attribute
sold
Index Errors
indexing failures
0
last indexing error
N/A
last indexing error key
N/A
identifier
price
attribute
price
Index Errors
indexing failures
0
last indexing error
N/A
last indexing error key
N/A
identifier
additionalInfo
attribute
additionalInfo
Index Errors
indexing failures
0
last indexing error
N/A
last indexing error key
N/A


I noted that the last key product:BUSINESS#imintest1@gmail.com##product#bolayam11, didn't contain the rating. Can you share the FT.INFO for idx:product? Which Search version are you using?

@AdrianoAmaral thanks for the reply. I've updated my question above with FT.INFO. How do I check which Search version I'm using?

INFO SEARCH or INFO MODULES

Noted that you have 3 documents indexed, even mentioning that you ingest only 2 documents:
num_docs = 3
Likewise, you get documents that weren't indexed:
Index Errors
indexing failures
8
last indexing error
Invalid geo string
last indexing error key
product:USER#test2@email.com##product#bolayam11
